# Unity3D canvas. How I can get camera?

Tags: android, canvas, unity-game-engine, camera

I use unity native UI in my project.
In scene I have GameObject "Canvas" and in this object I use some UI objects.
But I don't find any camera in Canvas and I don't know how to get it from code. In some task I need to transform ScreenPosition to WorldPosition but I can't.
Can anybody help me. How to get Camera in code or some alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [Canvas.worldCamera field](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-worldCamera.html) in the Canvas object that allows you to access the camera used to render the Canvas. This is only available if you use the render mode `Screen Space - Camera` or `World Space`. If you use render mode `Screen Space - Overlay` there isn't really a difference between world space and screen space from your canvas perspective, since the position of an element matches the pixel position it is rendered on-screen.

If you however have a separate camera for your 3D world and you want to convert between that camera's space and screen space, you can access it either using `Camera.main` (this will get the first camera with the tag `MainCamera`) or add a Camera field in your script and manually link the main camera from the inspector.